# getting error only one globalBindings customization is allowed in a whole compilation while using maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, xjb

I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin. Here is my plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-serviceoperations</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas/lmsapi/serviceoperations</schemaDirectory>
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-types</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas/lmsapi/types</schemaDirectory>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>schema-binding.xjb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

here is my schema-binding.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"
            parseMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.xsd.binder.XSDateTimeCustomBinder.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.xsd.binder.XSDateTimeCustomBinder.printDateTime" />

    <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xsd:date"
            parseMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.xsd.binder.XSDateCustomBinder.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.xsd.binder.XSDateCustomBinder.printDateTime" />

        <xjc:serializable uid="1" /> 
    </jaxb:globalBindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

I have an xsd `Enrollments.xsd`. In which I have date type. I want that any xsd with date or datetime type convert to Localdate or Localdatetime instead of XMLGregorianCalendar. here is the snippet

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Learner.xsd"/>
    ...
    <xsd:complexType name="LearnerEnrollCourses">  
        <xsd:sequence>  
            <xsd:element name="CourseId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="false"  />
        </xsd:sequence> 
        <xsd:attribute name="enrollmentStartDate" type="xsd:date" use="required" />
         <xsd:attribute name="enrollmentEndDate" type="xsd:date" use="required" /> 
    </xsd:complexType>
    ...
</xsd:schema>
```

Now when I right click on POM. select `Run As -> Maven generate-sources` then I am getting the following error

```
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/Basit/eclipse-jee-mars-2/workspace/360Training/Java%208/LS360ProxyAPI/LmsApiProxy/src/main/resources/schemas/schema-binding.xjb{12,26}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/D:/Basit/eclipse-jee-mars-2/workspace/360Training/Java%208/LS360ProxyAPI/LmsApiProxy/src/main/resources/schemas/schema-binding.xjb; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 26; only one globalBindings customization is allowed in a whole compilation
at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:86)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ErrorReporter.error(ErrorReporter.java:84)
....
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/Basit/eclipse-jee-mars-2/workspace/360Training/Java%208/LS360ProxyAPI/LmsApiProxy/src/main/resources/schemas/schema-binding.xjb{12,26}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/D:/Basit/eclipse-jee-mars-2/workspace/360Training/Java%208/LS360ProxyAPI/LmsApiProxy/src/main/resources/schemas/schema-binding.xjb; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 26; (related to above) but one is already given at this location
```

Although classes are generating. But type is still XMLGregorianCalendar.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LearnerEnrollCourses", propOrder = {
    "courseId"
})
public class LearnerEnrollCourses {

    @XmlElement(name = "CourseId", required = true)
    protected List<String> courseId;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "enrollmentStartDate", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar enrollmentStartDate;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "enrollmentEndDate", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar enrollmentEndDate;
```

What I am doing wrong in configuration and how can I solve it ?

Thanks

**---------------------EDIT-----------------------**

This plugin configuration is working.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-serviceoperations</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <schemaInclude>schemas/lmsapi/serviceoperations/*.xsd</schemaInclude>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <bindingInclude>schemas/schema-binding.xjb</bindingInclude>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc-types</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>schemas/lmsapi/types</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <schemaInclude>**/*.xsd</schemaInclude>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <schemaExcludes>
                    <schemaExclude>Enrollment.xsd</schemaExclude>
                </schemaExcludes>
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <extension>true</extension>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

here is my schema-binding.xjb

```
<jaxb:globalBindings>

    <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDateTime" xmlType="xsd:dateTime"
            parseMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.schema.binder.XSDateTimeCustomBinder.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.schema.binder.XSDateTimeCustomBinder.printDateTime" />

    <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.LocalDate" xmlType="xsd:date"
            parseMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.schema.binder.XSDateCustomBinder.parseDateTime"
            printMethod="com.softech.ls360.lms.api.proxy.schema.binder.XSDateCustomBinder.printDateTime" />

    <!-- Force all classes implements Serializable -->
    <xjc:serializable uid="1" />

</jaxb:globalBindings>


<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="lmsapi/types/Enrollment.xsd" node="/xsd:schema" >
    <jaxb:schemaBindings >
        <jaxb:package name="com.softech.vu360.lms.webservice.message.lmsapi.types.enrollment" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Here is my one of the files from serviceoperations and types directory

EnrollmentServiceOperations.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://enrollment.serviceoperations.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns="http://enrollment.serviceoperations.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns:enrolmnt="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns:tr="http://transactionresult.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://transactionresult.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="../types/TransactionResultType.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="../types/Enrollment.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="LearnerCoursesEnrollRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            ....
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    ....
</xsd:schema>
```

CustomerServiceOperations.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://customer.serviceoperations.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns="http://customer.serviceoperations.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns:cust="http://customer.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns:tr="http://transactionresult.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://transactionresult.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="../types/TransactionResultType.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://customer.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="../types/Customer.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="AddCustomerRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            ...
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    ...
</xsd:schema>
```

Types/Enrollment.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns="http://enrollment.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Learner.xsd"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="LearnerCourses">  
        ....  
    </xsd:complexType>
    ....
</xsd:schema>
```

types/Customer.xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://customer.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    xmlns="http://customer.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" 
    xmlns:addr="http://address.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://address.types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="Address.xsd"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="Customers">  
        <xsd:sequence>  
            ....
        </xsd:sequence>  
    </xsd:complexType>
    ...
</xsd:schema>
```

Now when I run `Run As -> Maven generate-sources`. It will generate serviceoperations sources in `src/main/java/com/..../serviceoperation/customer/AddCustomerRequest.java` and types sources in `src/main/java/com/.../types/customer/Customers.java`. Similar for others xsds.

Why shouldn't I use `<generateDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/</generateDirectory>`. This is what I want. I think this plugin is making packages from targetnamespace in each xsd. Am I right ?

If I am doing something wrong in configuring this plugin then please tell me so I can correct it. Like you said not to generate in src/main/java.

I want that all my xsds in serviceoperations folder `(src/main/resources/schemas/lmsapi/serviceoperation/*.xsd)` should generate in `src/main/java/com/..../serviceoperation/customer/*.java`, `src/main/java/com/..../serviceoperation/enrollment/*.java` folder and same for others.

All xsds in `(src/main/resources/schemas/lmsapi/types/*.xsd)` should generate in `src/main/java/com/..../types/customer/*.java`, `src/main/java/com/..../types/enrollment/*.java` folder and same for others.

And also my binding file apply to all xsds `(src/main/resources/schemas/schema-binding.xjb)` all xsds in servieoperations and types folder.

Is there any better way to configure this plugin then please tell me so I can correct it on my side. I am guessing you are the author of this plugin.

Thanks & Regards

Basit Mahmood Ahmed

Comment: Please post `mvn clean install -X` log. You should also *not* generate to `src/main/java` and [use separate target directories for separate executions](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Use-Separate-Target-Directories-for-Separate-Executions).

Comment: Kindly check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Still don't see the `mvn clean install -X` log. As for generation the code in `src/main/java`, you may do whatever you want, of course, but Maven convention is that generated code goes into `target/generated-source/<tool>`.

Comment: I'm still seeing this exception, what is the solution?

Answer (score 3):

Current status of that issue, to spare others frustration and searching...

This issue shows up randomly and is caused by a bug in JAXB implementation. The issue was reported [JAXB-687](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/687), however it is closed now, even though it is not fixed (see comment from suboptimal user posted on 16 Sep 2016).

Comment: I'm still getting this error and yes it seems to be random. How did you fix it in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem and solved it by changing the `java version from 1.8 -> 1.7`.

Alternatively removing `xjc:serializable uid="1"` worked, too.